# What is the limit of the deep field exploration?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, galaxies, telescopes

The [deep field exploration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Deep_Fields) is quite fascinating, first the Hubble Deep Field (HDF) showing a small piece of the Univers one billion year after the Big-Bang, next the Hubble Ultra-Deep Field (HUDF), and now the Hubble eXtreme Deep Field (XDF) showing galaxies 450 million years after the Big-Bang.

*Question*: what is the limit of deepness we can expect to observe (in term of million years after the Big-Bang)?

Note that by "limit" I do not mean the theoretical limit but the practical limit.
By "practical limit" I mean using a visible-light telescope (not necessarily Hubble).
We also allow infrared telescope for correcting the redshift phenomenon.
In particular, I'm not asking about the CMB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practical limit in terms of sky coverage is probably given by funding. The HDF, according to wikipedia, covers a 24-millionth of the entire sky. We would have to launch thousands of Hubble-like instruments to cover the entire sky at that resolution and sensitivity. Much of that area is covered by the Milky Way and and gas clouds, anyway, so not all deep exposures will reveal as much information as the HDF. Will we do this? Probably not, however, there is a lot to be learned from very precise whole sky maps because galactic shapes are being distorted by the irregular gravitational fields in the universe. This leads is to [weak gravitational lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_gravitational_lensing). Proposals like the [Euclid mission](http://www.euclid-ec.org/?page_id=2686) will use specially designed space telescopes with visible and near infrared capabilities that are similar (not quite as high resolution) as that of Hubble to map areas of sky that are hundreds of times larger than those that Hubble's very small angle cameras can take.

If we want to go earlier in time, then we have to use near- and mid-IR and eventually deep-IR telescopes. The first of these will be the new  [James Webb Space Telescope](http://www.jwst.nasa.gov/), which is the mission that will augment Hubble with the necessary IR capability. If you have been following the JWT in the news, you may have heard that in terms of funding it is very close to breaking the bank... it's a very ambitious and expensive instrument that eats into the budget of a lot of other potentially equally interesting science missions. For the foreseeable future it's the largest space telescope investment that we will be making, which brings us back to the funding limits...

Comment: I clarify my question: in term of million years after the Big-Bang, what is the limit of deepness we can expect to observe?

Comment: You can observe all the way back to the CMB, which we are working on, right now. The hunt for the earliest galaxies is on and that's why instruments in the mid- and even deep-IR are necessary. Sorry if I misunderstood your question... I kind of excluded the deep searches because you said that you are not asking about the CMB... but it's really a continuum search from 300,000 years after the big bang all the way to today's galaxies.

Comment: But in practice I don't think you can go up to 300,000 years with a visible-light telescope, moreover CMB is microwave (and so non-visible). The question is: we can go up to what?

Comment: Exactly. If you look at the James Webb Space Telescope, it's not built for the visible but primarily for the IR. Once we go beyond low redshift galaxies, the information we are interested in is at ever longer wavelengths. In other words... the Hubble was the largest visible space telescope, for now. That science is mostly done. What scientists care about is beyond the human visual range. That doesn't mean there won't be large visual space telescopes in the future... it's just not a scientific preference, for now. Eventually we will have exoplanet surface imagers... 50 years from now?

Comment: Quotation: << JWST will be able to see back to **about 200 million years after the Big Bang**. But why do we need to see infrared light to understand the early universe? Because light from these objects is shifted to the red. >>  Credit: Aleš Tošovský.  Source: http://jwst.nasa.gov/firstlight.html   You're right, I should allow IR for being relevant.

Comment: Well, your question has multiple dimensions which, eventually, all converge on technological limitations and funding. Do we know what we would like to measure? Hello, yeah! We would like to measure every bit of information that can be extracted from the sky (somebody made an estimate about that, I should look for it). Will we? Heck, no, it's way too expensive.

Comment: So JWST will be able to see back to about 200 million years after the Big Bang, and perhaps the next generation telescope after JWST will be able to see back to about 50 million years etc... what is limit in practice? (in term of years after the big-bang, and without considering funding aspect).

Comment: The practical limit in time is the CMB... but you explicitly said that you didn't want to hear about the CMB. We have all the technology necessary to see all the wavelengths in-between and there is, as far as I know, enough signal to noise ratio even with relatively small antennas, so there should be no limit. I don't know just how much relevant physics there is in the few million years after the surface of last scattering that created the CMB and before the first galaxies form. My understanding is that there could be some really interesting giant stars at that time.

Comment: If I understand well, more we want to see far in time and more the telescope should look large wavelengths: with visible-light telescope like Hubble, we can see up to 400 millions years after the Big-Bang, with IR telescope like JWST, we can see up to 200 millions years and with microwave telescope like Planck we can see at 300000 years. What about the time between 300000 and 200 millions? Is it possible in practice to build a telescope able to see for example at 10 million years with enough good resolution?

Comment: Yes, you can look at Wien's displacement law, pick the temperature of the object that you are interested in, apply the cosmological redshift that you are interested in and then you will arrive at a wavelength/frequency that you have to measure. The rest is basically all about building the best affordable imaging system for that wavelength. We can basically cover any wavelength you want these days with bolometers, so technically it's not a problem. The resolution limit is given by nature and the size of instrument you can afford.

Comment: Ok I see, there is no time limitation, but we can't see at 10 million years and 1 million years  with thet same resolution. The real limitation is the resolution at a given time. So I should reformulate the question as follows: what could be the practical limit in time to see with a resolution allowing to distinguish objects of galaxy lenght ?

Comment: The time limitation with electromagnetic waves is the CMB. There is no known principle resolution limit for the angular resolution. You can build ever larger observatories that have ever larger angular resolution. The only question is whether you are running out of money or useful physics first. At the moment it's probably money.

Comment: Using [the angular resolution formula for a telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution#Single_telescope) and trigonometry, we get that for having a galaxy lenght resolution on the CMB, we need a telescope of diameter D = 500 m.

Comment: That would be a perfectly doable telescope. Those kinds of facilities should be available by about 2050.

Comment: Is it a joke? If not, is there such long-term projects?

Comment: What do mean by "Is it a joke"? Are we well on our way to building interferometric arrays with such resolution? Yes.